# How to check if copy/paste options are disable in android with espresso

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I am kind of new to Android-espresso-Kotlin and I am trying to check if an application has the following type of menu disabled (paste option) using espresso android.
[image]

So far I have been able to make the menu appear with a longClick; but when the menu is deactivated I am having the issue with the following approach:

```
onView(withText("Paste"))
            .inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup())
            .check(doesNotExist())
```

As anticipated when the menu is deactivated I am getting the NoMatchingRootException exception caused there is no view with that text; so, What I would like to do is to check that the menu does not exist avoiding the exception (looking for it) or if you have a better approach I am open to any suggestions.

BTW: It seems that the menu popup is something not from the app and not being listed in the layout/views of the app.

Thanks!!